# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'

Tags: php, openssl

When i want connect to mysql via ssl:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname, $username, $password, array(
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem',
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem',
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem'
  )
);
$stmt = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;");
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

I gets

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): this stream
>   does not support SSL/crypto

and

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20180731/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/openssl.so: file too short)) in Unknown on line 0

How to fix that ?

Comment: WHat version of PHP are you using please

Comment: @RiggsFolly PHP 7.3.15-3